# AngularJS directive not working properly

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating an application in Django and Angular. I have created one custom Angular Directive as below:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('scrumboard.demo')
    .directive('scrumboardCard', CardDirective);

function CardDirective() {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/static/scrumboard/card.html'
        restrict: 'E'
    };
}
})();
```

And called it through custom HTML tag as below:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="card in list.cards">
        <scrumboard-card></scrumboard-card>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I can see that the directive is not being called at all. I even tried putting garbage code in the angular directive so as to generate error, but the page just loads without calling that angular directive.

Comment: PS: I have already created the angular module referenced in the function in another js file. And I have loaded all the JS files in order as below

**<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{% static "scrumboard/scrumboard.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scrumboard/card.directive.js" %}"></script>**

Comment: you have `<p>...</li>`, and `templateurl` instead of `templateUrl`, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, well spotted. It was a typo. ok I changed templateurl to templateUrl but it hasn't fixed the problem. My guess is that this directive is not called at all by the <scrumboard-card> tag that I have put in my html file. As I replaced all the code in this js file with garbage, but it just loaded the page without an error, without any data from this directive off course.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the title. Was meant as comment in the edit :o

Comment: You can debug it easily by doing this: `link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { console.log(elem) }` now check if the `elem` is logged in the console.

Comment: there is one more typo, you are missing a comma `,` between `templateUrl` and `restrict`, also check that `list.cards` array is not empty

Comment: I believe you are including your directive's js file correctly into your index.html

Comment: Yes first the angular library, the the main js and then the directive as this --> **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="{% static "scrumboard/scrumboard.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "scrumboard/card.directive.js" %}"></script>**

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. I had missed a comma after templateUrl line

Instead of this:

```
 templateUrl: '/static/scrumboard/card.html'
    restrict: 'E'
```

It should be this:

```
 templateUrl: '/static/scrumboard/card.html',
    restrict: 'E'
```

Comment: This was preventing the biding of directive to html element.